# String List in Where Condition

Tags: c#, linq

Below is my class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int  ID {get;set;}
    public IList<string> Tags {get;set;}

    Public Test()
    {
        Tags = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Now I have another list called `tags` which data type is `List<string>` with some values.

Now I want to write a query:

```
var results = List<Test>().Where(x=>x.Tags.Contains(tags));
```

But `tags` is not allowed inside `Contains`, since `Contains` allow only string type.

Actual error is:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' to 'string'

May I know how to handle this situation in Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to get all results where at least one tag is in your second list `tags`. You can use `Intersect` to do so:

```
var results = List().Where(x=>x.Tags.Intersect(tags).Any())
```

Comment: Actually I want to display all results from second list Tags. I used above syntax but i am getting error.

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
Cannot understand how to translate method 'Intersect' of 'System.Linq.Enumerable' type.

Comment: @mcpdeveloper That's why it's important to tell the whole story when asking a question. Apparently `List<Test>()` is an `IQueryable` from, probably, Entity Framework. So which EF version is this, which database provider, and how is `Test` mapped to the database? Please add this information to your question.

Comment: @mcpdeveloper You did not write that you use any ORM framework. When you ask a question next time, please provide all information necessary to answer the question direcetly.

Comment: Just to add :  I am using like below                                                                                    var results = RavenSession.Query<SomeClass>().Where(x=>x.Tags.Intersect(tags).Any()).                                     
                                                                                                        RavenSession.Query  is an IRavenQueryable.

Answer (score 1):

So you give us some code that doesn't do what you want, and you want us to write code that does do what you want.

Wouldn't it be nice if you told us what your want?

I'll try to make a good guess.

So you have a sequence of `Tests`, where every `Test` has a property `Tags`, which is a sequence of strings.

You also have a sequence of `Tags`, which is also a sequence of strings.

```
IEnumerable<Test> tests = ...
IEnumerable<string> tags = ...
```

Which of the following four do you want?

**I want only those Tests that have**

- a value for property Tags equal to Tags (same values, same order)
- exactly the same Tags that are in tags (same values, any order)
- have at least all Tags that are in sequence of Tags (more values)
- have only Tags that are in my sequence of Tags (less values)

### Tags equal to tags: same value, same order

For this, use one of the [overloads of Enumerable.SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-5.0)

```
var result = tests.Where(test => test.Tags.SequenceEqual(tags));
```

In words: from all `tests`, keep only those Tests that have a sequence of strings in property `Tags` that is exactly the same sequence as we have in `tags`: same number of strings, in the same order.

If you want, you can use an equality comparer, for instance:

```
IEqualityComparer<string> tagComparer = StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var result = tests.Where(test => test.Tags.SequenceEqual(tags, tagComparer));
```

### Exactly the same Tags that are in tags: same values, any order

For this it is wise to put your tags in a `HashSet<string>`, this is a fast method to see if two sequences have the same elements:

```
HashSet<string> setTags = new HashSet<string>(tags);
var result = tests.Where(test => setTags.SetEquals(test.Tags));
```

SetEquals returns true if exactly the same elements, in any order, duplicates are ignored.

Or course, you can use an equality comparer:

```
HashSet<string> setTags = new HashSet<string>(tags, tagComparer);
```

There is a wee problem here:

```
tags = new string[] {"1", "1", "1", "1","1", "1", "1", "1"}
Test = new Test
{
    Tags = new string[] {"1", "1"},
    ...
}
```

Do you want to keep this test? Let's ignore the duplicates.

### at least all Tags that are in sequence of Tags: more values

Once you've created the HashSet, the other two are easy

### At least all Tags that are in sequence of Tags: more values

```
var result = tests.Where(test => setTags.IsSuperSetOf(test.Tags));
```

### Only Tags that are in my sequence of Tags: less values

```
var result = tests.Where(test => setTags.IsSubSetOf(test.Tags));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution as far as I understood:

> var results = List().Where(x=> x.Tags.Any(y => tags.Any(z => z == y)));

It is however not optimal and might be slow in case if the tag lists are big and the solution above is better. But it is still a solution.